# Reading Xml elements to Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to read an xml to excel, and extract the elements and attributes.

for e.g: < Cookies price="100.00" /> is my element.

I want to populate **'Cookies' in one column and its price '100' in another column**. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If your tags are in `Column A`, enter the below formula in `Column B` and drag down,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"<",""),"/>",""))," ",","),"=",",")
```

[image]

Copy the `Column B` data and paste to `Column C` with paste special.

[image]

Then select `column C` and click Data --> Text to columns and use delimiter as `,` and press finish.

[image]